# Firebase cloudstore collections map vs. forEach

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use the map function to create an array of the items returned from a collection.

My implementation is using the forEach to iterate which works fine. However, I can't get it to work with the map function.

Here's the code:

```js
firestore.collection("notes").doc(this.props.id).collection('items').get()
.then((snap) => {
    let items = []
    snap.forEach((doc) => {
        items.push({id:doc.id,text:doc.data().text})
        console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`);
    });
    console.log(items)
});
```

However, this doesn't work:

```js
firestore.collection("notes").doc(this.props.id).collection('items').get()
.then((snap) => {
    let items = snap.map((doc) => {
        return {id:doc.id, text:doc.data().text}
    })
    console.log(items)
});
```

It shoots an error that 'snap.map' is not a function.

I can't figure out where I'm tripping?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [forEach](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#forEach) method exists, but not map.

However you can get an array of [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs):

> An array of all the documents in the QuerySnapshot.

Which you can call map on, like this:

```
let items = snap.docs.map(doc => {
    return { id: doc.id, text: doc.data().text }
})
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. I've been pulling my hair out for hours trying to work out why snapshot.forEach() would work and not Object.values(snapshot).map() would not. Your method works.

Answer (score 1):

`snap` may not be a true array. It's probably some sort of array-like object. Try creating a new array with the spread operator (`...`), then working on that, like this:

```
firestore.collection("notes").doc(this.props.id).collection('items').get()
.then((snap) => {
    let items = [...snap].map((doc) => {
        return {id:doc.id, text:doc.data().text}
    })
    console.log(items)
});
```

That should convert it to a true array which will give you the ability to use the `.map` function.

Answer (score 0):

A little example, in my case, Im update something:

```
const query = ...collection("notes").doc(this.props.id).collection('items');

query.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
     changes.map(a => {
     const id = a.payload.doc.id;
     this.db.collection("notes").doc(this.props.id).collection('items').update({
            someItemsProp: newValue,
                })
            })
        }).subscribe();
    }
```